# Solving Differential equation appearing in resonant circuit

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Mainly I'am asked to solve the Differential equation:
$$\ddot{I}+\dfrac{R}{L}\,\dot{I}+\dfrac{1}{L\,C}\,I = \dfrac{U_0}{L}\,\omega\,\cos(\omega\,t)$$

For the sake of simplicity let's rename that:
$$\ddot{I}+\beta\,\dot{I}+\omega_e\,I = U\,\omega\,\cos(\omega\,t)$$

I'm now suggested to utilise: $\cos(\omega\,t) = e^{i\,\omega\,t}$ and solving with Ansatz: $I(t) = A\,e^{i\,\omega\,t}, \quad A\in \mathbb{C}$

So just plugging that into the original Differential equation yields:
$$(-\omega^2+i\,\omega\,\beta+w_e)\,A = U\,\omega$$

Now I can't help but writing $a\,e^{i\,\varphi}$ for $A$. It helps solving the equation immensely:
$$(-\omega^2+i\,\omega\,\beta+w_e)\,a\,e^{i\varphi} = U\,\omega$$
respectively spelled out with Eulers Identity and brought to the other side:
$$(-\omega^2+i\,\omega\,\beta+w_e)\,a = U\,\omega\,(\cos(-\varphi)+i\sin(-\varphi))$$
Now, that allows a comparison of coefficients:
$$\begin{align} 
&(w_e-\omega^2)\,a= U\,\omega\,\cos(-\varphi) \quad &\textbf{I}\\\\
&(i\,\omega\,\beta)\,a = U\,\omega \,i\,\sin(-\varphi) \quad &\textbf{II}\\\\
&\text{the complex number cancels out nicely:} \\\\
&(\omega\,\beta)\,a = U\,\omega\,\sin(-\varphi) \quad &\textbf{II}
\end{align}$$

For finding $a$, here $\textbf{$I^2+II^2$}$ brings:
$$\left(((w_e-\omega^2)^2+(\omega\,\beta)^2\right)\,a^2 = (U\,\omega)^2\left(\cos^2(\varphi)+\sin^2(\varphi)\right)$$

hence also by trigonometric Identity:
$$a = \dfrac{U\,\omega}{\sqrt{((w_e-\omega^2)^2+(i\,\omega\,\beta)^2}}$$

I actually don't know why I mentioned all of that, probably because it builds up to my question. Even if the solution seems right I have trouble finding the angle $\varphi$

It plainly seems to be obtained by $\textbf{$\dfrac{I}{II}$}$:
$$\dfrac{\omega\,\beta}{\omega_e-\omega^2} = -\tan(\varphi)$$

First I was worrying because the angel was negative, but it seems to fit the final solution:
$$I = A\,e^{i\,\omega\,t} = a\,e^{i\,\varphi+i\,\omega\,t} = a\left(\cos(\omega\,t+\varphi)+i\,\sin(\omega\,t+\varphi)\right)$$

To be honest, most questions vanished while writing this. Only question left would be: Why am I just taking the real part of the solution and ignoring the imaginary part, even tho it is still persistent? In other words: why just: $$I = a\left(\cos(\omega\,t+\varphi)\right) \quad ?$$

Comment: Because this is a linear differential equation, the pieces of a complex solution are also solutions (at least in the homogeneous case).  Since you started with a cosine, and replaced it with a complex exponential, what you really have is the "real part of" the complex exponential.  So when you solve it, you want only the real part.

Comment: The use of a complex variable in solving such differential equations is actually just a computational convenience (as you observed).  These problems _can_ be solved using only real-valued functions, but the work becomes somewhat awkward.  (Engineers used such devices as "phasors" and Smith charts to make the calculations when complex numbers were not as widely taught.)

Comment: makes sense to me. Also thx for the historical background.